# Okular annotations - *.xml file path and correct colour issue

Tags: pdf, okular

The review highlights made in okular are stored in ~/.kde/share/apps/okular/docdata/ , with a *.xml file for each annotated *.pdf.

***1st question:***
How can I change the path of the xml annotations to be the same path of the *.pdf? Therefore when I would change the pdf from my computer to a pen or external disk, the *.xml file would go in the same folder - and wouldn't be lost in the standard folder.

***2nd question:***
The underline tool hides the bottom of each line:
[image: highlight tool in okular]

How can I correct it in order to do not override the bottom of each text line?

obs.:
In order to underline with yellow or other colours, I have edited a file of the okular settings stored in: /usr/share/kde4/apps/okular/tools.xml . By changing that file I was able to add more review colours for underlining, by adding code analogous to this:

```
<tool id="9" name="Black Underlining" pixmap="tool-underline-okular">
    <tooltip>Underline the text with a black line</tooltip>
    <engine type="TextSelector" color="#000000">
        <annotation type="Underline" color="#000000" />
    </engine>
    <shortcut>9</shortcut>
</tool>
```

and then, replacing id, shortcut and color respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st part:

In order to export the annotations to other computer we can export the document as a *.okular file (which corresponds to a zip file with the *.pdf + *.xml files). In this case, to read the annotations in the other computer, the okular program is needed in both computers.
Alternatively I have read that the newer versions of okular compiled with poppler 0.20 do have the option to export to a pdf with annotations (though, I don't have it now).

2nd part:

Go to "Settings -> Show navigation panel"; then in "Reviews" view the annotations; click with the right button in each "Highlight"; then click in "Properties"; after that choose the type to "Squiggly" (as in fig.1, [squiggly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WctKe.png)) or "Underline" with opacity 70% (as in fig.2, [underline with opacity 70%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjaWN.png)).

obs: it is possible to choose more colours than the default black (eg. yellow) in the "General" tab (alternatively of editing the code, as mentioned in the question) - in fact, by editing the code a permanent new "highlight yellow button" would be added, whereas if the change is made in the GUI the colour must be changed for each annotation if yellow is the desired colour.

[image]
 [image]